# How to find the difference between two timestamped rows whenever value changes between rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

My Data Set looks like this:

[image: My Data Set looks like this:]

The Output given in column D  is derived as follows:

1. Output against index 2 : TimeStamp in Index 3 - TimeStamp in Index 2
2. Output against index 6 : TimeStamp in Index 10 - TimeStamp in Index 6
3. Output against index 12 : TimeStamp in Index 15 - TimeStamp in Index 12

DataSet MySQL V2012

```
create table #temp11 (Index# int, TimeStamp# Datetime, Alarm int)

insert into #temp11 values
(1, '10/6/2019 00:08:01', 0),
(2, '10/6/2019 00:08:13'    ,1),
(3, '10/6/2019 00:08:15'    ,1),
(4, '10/6/2019 00:10:47'    ,0),
(5, '10/6/2019 00:10:58'    ,0),
(6, '10/6/2019 00:10:59'    ,1),
(7, '10/6/2019 00:11:00'    ,1),
(8, '10/6/2019 00:11:01'    ,1),
(9, '10/6/2019 00:11:02'    ,1),
(10, '10/6/2019 00:11:03'   ,1),
(11, '10/6/2019 00:11:04'   ,0),
(12, '10/6/2019 00:11:05'   ,1),
(13, '10/6/2019 00:11:06'   ,1),
(14, '10/6/2019 00:11:07'   ,1),
(15,'10/6/2019 00:11:15'    ,1)
```

TIA

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variant of the gaps-and-islands problem. Here is one way to solve it using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
select 
    t.*,
    case when 
        alarm = 1 
        and row_number() over(partition by alarm, rn1 - rn2 order by TimeStamp) = 1
    then timestampdiff(
            second,
            min(TimeStamp) over(partition by alarm, rn1 - rn2),
            max(TimeStamp) over(partition by alarm, rn1 - rn2)
        )
    end out
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(order by TimeStamp) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by alarm order by TimeStamp) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
```

The inner query ranks record in the whole table and in partition of records sharing the same alarm. The difference between the ranks gives you the group each record belong to.

Then, the outer query identifies the first record in each group with `alarm = 1`, and computes the difference between the first and last record in the group, in seconds.

Comment: Hey GMB, 
Thank you for the for the quick response. But the query give the solution for only 1st output row. Remaining all rows comes blank. 
Can you please re-check the query...
Thanks

Comment: @Sanjeev: I see... fixed.

Comment: Alternatively to simplify the query you can use windows functions like Lead/Lag based on the requirement